# error with stored procedure logic

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

I am trying to do something similar to 
[How can I improve this SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198330/how-can-i-improve-this-sql-query)

However, in there logic
Essentially I have a list of IDs that could have multiple values associated with them, the values being Yes, No, or some other string. **For ID x, if any of the values are a Yes, x should be Yes, if they are all No, it should be No, if they contain any other values but yes and no, display that value. I only want to return 1 row per ID, no duplicates.**

but in my logic if all values are yes, then display yes, if all values are no then display no, if it is a mix of yes,no or anything else display mix

```
DECLARE @tempTable table ( ID int, Val varchar(1) )

    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 10, 'Y')
    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 11, 'N')
    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 11, 'N')
    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 12, 'Y')
    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 12, 'Y')
    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 12, 'Y')
    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 13, 'N')
    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 14, 'Y')
    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 14, 'N')
    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 15, 'Y')
    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 16, 'Y')
    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 17, 'F')
    INSERT INTO @tempTable ( ID, Val ) VALUES ( 18, 'P')


    SELECT DISTINCT t.ID, COALESCE(t2.Val, t3.Val, t4.Val)
    FROM @tempTable t
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID, Val
        FROM @tempTable
        WHERE Val = 'Y'
    ) t2 ON t.ID = t2.ID
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
        ID, Val FROM @tempTable
        WHERE Val = 'N'
    ) t3 ON t.ID = t3.ID
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID, Val
        FROM @tempTable
        WHERE Val <> 'Y' AND Val <> 'N'
    ) t4 ON t.ID = t4.ID

Update dbo.households
SET dbo.households.code = #TempTable.code
FROM #TempTable
WHERE dbo.households.id = #TempTable.id
```

Comment: for some reason if a result comes as N,N,P it still shows N or if it comes out Y,N it will show Y. I want Y,Y to come out as Y and N,N to come out as N and everything else to come out as 'M'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT  ID ,
        CASE WHEN MAX(Val) = MIN(Val)
                  AND MAX(Val) IN ( 'N', 'Y' ) THEN MAX(Val)
             ELSE 'M'
        END
FROM    @tempTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Or a version that returns `Y` if *any* exist rather than if *all* are `Y`

```
SELECT  ID ,
        ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Val = 'Y' THEN 'Y' END), 
               CASE WHEN MAX(Val) = MIN(Val) THEN MAX(Val)
                              ELSE 'M'
                         END)
FROM    @tempTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Or a final version that takes literally the "if they contain any other values but yes and no, display that value." statement.

```
SELECT  ID ,
        ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Val = 'Y' THEN 'Y'END), 
               ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN Val NOT IN ( 'N', 'Y' ) THEN Val END), 
                      MAX(Val)))
FROM    @tempTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: @antisanity `14` has both `y` and `n` so `m` is what is required.

Comment: @antisanity - Ah I see what you mean. There are 2 contradictory specs in the question itself. I assume one of them is describing the current behaviour and the other the desired behaviour. I'll add a version that does the bolded spec,

Comment: @antisanity - Having just read the spec again I can see where you're coming from on that but I'm not going to do any further edits until the OP clarifies the requirement.

Comment: Changed my mind but that is the last edit without any additional input from the OP!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `max()` since it's a char value. Give this a whirl:

*Note: The logic employed here is that Non-Y/N > Any Y > Only N*

**[Edit]** Refactored & simplified:

```
select
 t.ID
,isnull(max(nyn.Val),max(yn.Val)) as Val
from @tempTable as t    
    left join @tempTable as nyn -- Non-Y/N value
    on nyn.ID = t.ID
    and nyn.Val not in ('Y','N')
    left join @tempTable as yn -- Y/N value
    on yn.ID = t.ID
    and yn.Val in ('Y','N')
group by t.ID
```

Yields the following results:

```
ID  Val
10  Y
11  N
12  Y
13  N
14  Y
15  Y
16  Y
17  F
18  P
```

Comment: thanks but for some reason my update statement isnt working but the result when i execute the query is. so basically i am getting correct results now, but my update query is giving me the old values

Comment: ahh so if a record has both a y and a n you will return both rows?

Comment: +1 BTW regarding the earlier comment in your answer about CTEs and SQL Server 2000 derived tables are still available if that's any use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it. I use MAX() in case more than one value return other than Y and N

```
SELECT  
  ID,
  CASE  
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tempTable tt WHERE t.ID = tt.ID AND tt.Val = 'Y')
             THEN 'Y'
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM @tempTable tt WHERE t.ID = tt.ID AND tt.Val NOT IN ('Y','N')) 
             THEN (SELECT MAX(Val) FROM @tempTable  tt WHERE t.ID = tt.ID AND tt.Val NOT IN ('Y','N'))
    ELSE 'N'
  END           
FROM    @tempTable t
GROUP BY ID
```